# Display image of storage in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Any ideas on how can I show the image from storage. I can't get the format right. I notice that using post.media in image source makes the whole record dispear in inspection. But once i remove it or place a random image url from the internet, post.media echos the imagine file name on h3

```
<div v-for="post in posts" v-bind:key="post.id" class="py-3">
        <div class="card">
            <img  src="{{ Storage::url('public/uploads/{{ post.media }})' }}" class="card-img-top">
            <div class="card-body">
            <h3>{{ post.media }}</h3>
            <p>{{ post.description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are using `vue`, I dont think it will recognize `Storage::url()`. First, create a symbolic link from **storage** to **public**. `php artisan storage:link`

Second, create a **computed property** `link`.

```
computed: {
    link(){
        return '/uploads/' + this.post.media;
    }
}
```

And simply,

```
<img src="post.link">
```

Comment: Not quite there. when inspect, post.link showing as the source

Comment: get warmer. v-bind:src has to be used. just trying to figure how i work the javascript in with the php

Comment: @ShawnSonnier honestly I'm confused to this question, you said that the source is showing, but the image does not show. And another *javascript in with the php*. Hmm.. I think there someone else could solve your problem. wait for it :)